# Pyspark save to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a large file to an Amazon S3 bucket.
Following code works perfectly:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame([('1', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '6')], ["A", "B"]).select('A').repartition(1).write \
    .format("text") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("header", "false") \
    .option("codec", "gzip") \
    .save("s3n://BUCKETNAME/temp.txt")
```

saving my full dataframe however fails. with following error in my notebook:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1274.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
    at org.jets3t.service.model.StorageObject.getLastModifiedDate(StorageObject.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:176)
```

In the spark application UI the job is described as succeeded.

I have following configuration:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.multipart.uploads.enabled", "true")
```

Trying to debug I tried the following, which works as it should...

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(full_df.select('columnA').take(5),['columnA']).select('columnA').repartition(1).write \
    .format("text") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("header", "false") \
    .option("codec", "gzip") \
    .save("s3n://BUCKETNAME/temp.txt")
```

I found following link which seems to be about this problem, but I can't find a working package
[Jets3t](https://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/pull-requests/38/archiveorg-support/diff)

Who can help with this mysterious error?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to s3a over S3n, with the Hadoop 2.7 JARs. S3n's time is over —it's just left alone to stop regressions.

Comment: This gives me a
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o631.save.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerConfiguration.setMultipartUploadThreshold(I)V`

This seems to be because of the hadoop version.
in my spark-defaults.conf I have the following:
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2
Which seems to be consistent with [this page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12420)
However the hadoop installed is `hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.7.1`

This is something that can't be changed though...